# One-to-many relationship returns null in Entity Framework

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I am trying to make relationships in Entity Framework and my SQL Server with Fluent API. Here's how I insert:

```
CREATE TABLE Product (
    id INT PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL IDENTITY(1,1),
    name VARCHAR(255)
);

CREATE TABLE OrderLine (
    id INT PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL IDENTITY(1,1),
    productId INT NOT NULL,
    FOREIGN KEY (productId) REFERENCES Product(id)
);
```

Now, `product` has many `orderLine`s, but does not know them and does not need to know them. We don't need to pick a single product and count the amount of orderlines, for example. Here's how it looks:

```
public class Product {
    public int id { get; set; }

    public string name { get; set; }

    public ICollection<OrderLine> orderLines { get; set; } //not needed but we'll have it anyway
}
```

```
public class OrderLine {
    public int id { get; set; }

    public int productId { get; set; }

    public Product product { get; set; }
}
```

According to [entityframeworktutorial.net](http://www.entityframeworktutorial.net/code-first/configure-one-to-many-relationship-in-code-first.aspx) this could should work:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<Product>()
    .HasMany<OrderLine>(s => s.orderLines)
    .WithRequired(s => s.product)
    .HasForeignKey(s => s.productId);
```

However, `product` is simply null when I try to pull it out of the database. Is this not a one-to-many relationship? I'm not quite sure where I went wrong.

Comment: Did you include the property in your query like `db.OrderLines.Include( e => e.product ).ToList();`?

Comment: @SirRufo No, I'm not sure how to do that. We have an `Order` which has a list of `OrderLines` which has a `Product`. So it goes something like: `db.Orders.First().orderLines.First().product.name` if that makes sense. Grab the first order, grab the first orderline, grab the product and give me the name.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'm not sure if this is the entire problem, as theres not that much information there, but in order to lazy load (which it looks like you are trying) the navigation properties must be marked as virtual like so...

```
public virtual Product product { get; set; }
```

otherwise EF's proxy can't wrap them and do its stuff.

Comment: Okay, I did not know Product had to be virtual as well. I only had it on productId. Thanks a lot, works now!

Answer (score 5):

If you have the lazyloading not enabled EF dont get the related entities by default.
Try include the entities that you need when you selecting the data:

```
var product = _db.OrderLine.Include(p=>p.Product)
```

Other solution is activate the lazyloading on modelBuilder, but be aware that to complex queries or large tables this can cause a big hit on application performance.